# Работа с COM объектами в NodeJS

Tags: node.js, com, activex, ole

Платформа windows, нашел только winax, но он работает только с ActiveX компонентами. И win32com еще есть, но он не совместим с 8 версией node. Можно ли как-нибудь через ActiveX обратиться к COM объекту или посоветуйте альтернативные варианты?